# Elision in "Good point" --> / gʊ pɔɪnt/ or not?

Tags: phonology

Is there an omission in pronouncing the word "good" when it happens with words starting with /p/ /b/? I mean, is it pronounced as /gu poınt/ in good point or like /gud poınt/?

If there is, is it due to elision in linguistics or another rule? Or maybe because /d/ is a voiced stop and /p/ is a voicless stop, it's easier to pronouce it that way?

I searched in some linguistics books like Fulk, Fromkin, and yule's books, but no clues I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In careful speech, it's pronounced [gʊd pɔɪnt] in American English. In maximally casual speech it's generally pronounced [gʊ Xpɔɪnt], where "X" means that there may be some elongation of /p/. However, that could simply be an automatic timing adjustment of an intervocalic consonant at a foot-juncture: you don't get [ʊ ɪ ɛ] foot-finally and there is evidence that a following consonant gets attached to the preceding syllable, keeping those vowels out of final position. Between those speech styles there are various kinds of phonetic overlap in articulators where there is lingual raising but it is mostly acoustically masked by the following labial closure.

It happens, so it depends on what you mean by "rule". If your universe of things includes rules of phonetic implementation (some people deny that they exist) then yes, this is due to a rule, specifically one of phonetic implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The alveolar consonant /d/, like the alveolar consonants /t/ and /n/, is highly unstable in English. It will tend to change its place of articulation according to the sound coming afterwards (it will assimilate its place of articulation). In the phrase *good point* the sound after the /d/ is a /p/. The phoneme /p/ is made with the lips—we say that it is *bilabial*. For this reason the /d/ may also become bilabial. It will remain a lenis ('voiced') consonant, and it will still be a plosive. This means that it will have become a /b/. So what you will actually hear in that case is:

- /gʊb pɔɪnt/ (goob point)

This can also happen if the /d/ occurs before a /b/:

- /gʊb bʊk/ (goob book)

It will occasionally happen when a /d/ occurs before /w/:

- /reb waɪn/ (reb wine)

If the /d/ occurs before a /k/ or a /g/, it may become a /g/:

- /gʊg kɔ:l/ (goog call)
- /gʊg gri:f/ (goog grief)

This is often referred to as dealveolar assimilation, because the consonant is moving away from its normal alveolar position, to effectively become a different consonant.

**The Original poster's question:**

There will be no elision of the /d/ in this environment. However we *are* likely to get dealveolar assimilation. Because this consonant will now be homorganic (made with the same parts of the mouth) with the following /p/, it will not be released and may be less easy to hear. There will also be some devoicing of the /d/ because of the following voiceless /p/, and so it may appear more /p/-like.

---

<sup>**Note:** I've used the British English transcription system used by John Wells in LPD for this post.</sup>

Comment: As far as I know, the "voiced" consonants in English are actually realised as voiceless in most dialects, and the distinction between the "voiced, unvoiced" pairs is made in the aspiration. Thus, when two plosives of the same place of articulation occur beside each other, the first is realised the same (unvoiced, unaspirated), regardless of whether it is phonemically voiced or not.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM That's not quite correct. So-called voiced consonants, (better terms *lenis* for several reasons) may become partially or sometimes fully devoiced **when next to voiceless sounds**, including silence. The devoicing in such instances may be total but will more frequently be partial, so in the word *bob*, if said in isolation, we would expect the beginning of the first [b] to be devoiced and the end of the second. We'd expect the same sort of effect with a series of two homorganic consonants. The aspiration of the initial consonant of the second word will to be affected.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM You'll see exactly the same aspiration for the initial consonant in *pie* whether it's in *top pie* or *fish pie.* [As you'll be able to see from the waveform for *newsitem* in this post here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288730/unvoiced-dʒ-and-ʒ-in-word-final-position/288765#288765), we often expect voiced consonants to be voiced the whole way through!

Comment: While dealveolar assimilation resulting in a geminate labial is certainly more common (I’d say virtually universal except in very careful speech), I don’t find elision to be unnatural at all either. In a context like “That’s a good point”, a pronunciation like [ˈazəˌgʊˈpʰɔɪ̃ʔ] with complete elision sounds perfectly natural to me. Certainly more natural than full dealveolar assimilation before /w/ to [bw], which is something I’d expect from a child, but rarely from adults. Elision seems to be far less likely before voiced stops, so “That’s a good book” wouldn’t normally be [ˈazəˌgʊˈbʊk].

Comment: @cmw Ah, you've heard it thousands of times. It's just that you're language brain told you it was a /d/! Yes, there's thousands of recordings in phonetics labs all around the world. This is really English Phonetics 101. [Here' a YouTube video on assimilation, example at around 33 secs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhUmqINw_gQ). Or see any university website on English phonetics/phonology. [Or see paragraph (b) in this book](https://tinyurl.com/5h3ezsbk)!

Comment: @Araucaria-him I was not talking about the second consonant, I was referring to the first. "top pie" and (theoretically) "tob pie" sound the exact same, as there is no aspiration on the bilabial plosive of "top/tob" to indicate whether or not it is phonemically voiced are not, since they are both unvoiced phonetically.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM Post-vocalic voiced stops are generally not devoiced – they retain voicing, at least at the beginning. Moreover, vowels are somewhat lengthened before voiced stops, and before unvoiced stops a glottal stop or glottalisation is usually inserted. So _top pie_ and _tob pie_ would be clearly distinguishable in normal speech, for multiple reasons.

Comment: @cmw It’s not a regionalism. It’s found absolutely everywhere, in all major English dialects across the US, Canada, England, Wales, Scotland, Ireland, Australia, New Zealand, South Africa, etc. The only place where I can imagine it possibly not applying is in some forms of Caribbean English, which have a tendency to ‘over-enunciate’ (e.g., having full assibilation and aspiration on the /t/ in _Batman_). If your tongue is touching your teeth when you say _good boy_, you are categorically a minority, because generally it doesn’t even do that in _good_ on its own (outside New York).

Answer (score 1):

The [d] in "good point" is lost by a most curious mechanism.  A familiar fact about midwestern (and other) English is that [t] in the offset of a syllable, when a consonant follows, can change to a glottalized [t'] or a glottal stop [?].

But why, one might wonder, does the voicelessness of the [t] help trigger this change?  Why doesn't the same thing happen to [d] as happens to [t]?  Well, it does.  Except a glottalized [d'] is difficult, and it is even harder when the oral alveolar closure is lost, because then what is left is a voiced glottal stop.

The voiced glottal stop, though, is not possible, since it requires the glottis to be both closed and partially open.  This sound segment self-destructs, and we hear nothing.

Comment: thanks 4 the answer. Does the speaker themselves understand this boiced glottal stop? Before you answer I was pronouncing the phrase and wandered what was the thing I felt befor /p/ sound happen. It was something like /ə/ but not that much deep. Is this the same with the glottal stop, you did me a favore and described? BTW, after that it seems /p/ is dubled or as it's called prolonged. Is it naturally this way or I am pronouncing it this way?

Comment: @Sina That 'prolonged' p you're hearing is most likely  a /bp/ cluster.

Comment: @Araucaria What about that /ə/ like sound, is it a voiced glottal stop. I mean can we feel it, or the thing I feel is that?

Comment: @Sina, When the stress contour of "good point" is 0 1, in very casual pronunciation, I think the [d] can be entirely missing.  When the contour is 3 1, that is with a low level of stress on the first syllable,  it seems possible to have something at the end of the first syllable which is not [b] (though that is also possible), not prolongation of either the preceding vowel or the following [p].  I've worried about this, but further I cannot go.  Voiced glottal stop?  If that is even possible, "maybe" is the best I can do.